# Block insert via Matrix3d can have attributes?

Tags: c#, autocad

Good Day,

I'm trying to create a csharp program to insert multiple blocks onto an Autocad drawing, each one with a different insert point. For simplicity given the block is another drawing I'm using a matrix insert that I'll paste below.
The problem is that the block I'm bringing in has text attributes that I need my program to be able to change.

Is there any way to keep using the insert method below while still managing to edit the block attributes as I insert it? and then edit it differently on the second insertion?

```
        using (tr)
        {
            Vector3d blockDisplacement1 = new Vector3d(ptInsert.Value.X, ptInsert.Value.Y, ptInsert.Value.Z);

            double blockScale = 1.0;

            string blockPath = @"T:\test.dwg";

            Database tmpDb = new Database(false, true);
            tmpDb.ReadDwgFile(blockPath, System.IO.FileShare.Read, true, "");

            Matrix3d Transform = Matrix3d
                        .Scaling(blockScale, Point3d.Origin)
                        .PreMultiplyBy(Matrix3d.Displacement(blockDisplacement1))
                        .PreMultiplyBy(ed.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem);

            db.Insert(Transform, tmpDb, true);

            tr.Commit();
            tr.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible.  Once you have the block inserted into your active drawing, you can modify the existing attribute values or open the block table record and add entirely new entities.

Here's a couple of blog articles to get you started:

http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/06/inserting-a-block-with-attributes-to-modelspace.html

http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-2107599E-9405-4D8B-A6DD-83D603B41568